# JSON Schema Not Support Some Regex Pattern

Tags: json, jsonschema

> My Json Schema :

```
{
   "type" : "object" ,
   "properties" : {
      "status" : {
        "type" : "string" ,
        "pattern" : "(OPEN|CLOSE)/i"
      } ,
      "phone" : {
        "type" : "string" ,
        "pattern" : "[0-9a-zA-Z_\\s]+"
    }
  }
}
```

> My Input :

```
{
   "status" : "open" ,
   "phone" : "9080245591"
}
```

I try to check the input using json schema.But json validator throw the following error. `pattern` value is wrong.So how to solve it.
and it throw `String 'open' does not match regex pattern '(OPEN|CLOSE)/i'.` this error also

Comment: please post your code also

Comment: i am use online validator. it also throw error.My validator tool is https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/

Comment: As others, I cannpt make sense of your regex for phone. Please use https://www.debuggex.com and set type to javascript.

Comment: my phone regex pattern allowed any country phone  number. Some Country take his language letter.So wrote this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found two issues in your schema:

1. Currently the specification does not allow you to specify flags like `/i` for case insensitive matching. You can address this by adding the flag to the expression itself `(?i)`.
2. You're specifying an `InBasicLatin` character set. That should bre `IsBasicLatin`.

The fixed schema:

```
{
   "type" : "object" ,
   "properties" : {
      "status" : {
        "type" : "string" ,
        "pattern" : "^(?i)(OPEN|CLOSE)$"
      } ,
      "phone" : {
        "type" : "string" ,
        "pattern" : "[0-9a-zA-Z_\\-\\.\\$@\\?\\,\\:\\'\\/\\!\\P{IsBasicLatin}\\s]+"
    }
  }
}
```

Note: I can't make sense of your pattern for `phone`, so I just fixed the error but otherwise didn't touch it.

Comment: But your status property pattern is wrong. It work like endswith `open` or `close`

Comment: My pattern is neither wrong nor right because you didn't provide any specifications of what input should and shouldn't be allowed. I just fixed the error in your pattern.

Comment: oh sorry Robby Cornelissen. status value is allowed only `open` | `close`.So how to i am fix it

Comment: Updated my answer. I think you're gonna want to take a long hard look at your phone pattern as well.